# Incorporating multiple lists in one text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastq

I am new to coding and I ran in trouble while trying to make my own fastq masker. The first module is supposed to trim the line with the + away, modify the sequence header (begins with >) to the line number, while keeping the sequence and quality lines (A,G,C,T line and Unicode score, respectively).

```
class Import_file(object):

def trim_fastq (self, fastq_file):
    f = open('path_to_file_a', 'a' )
    sanger = []
    sequence = []
    identifier = []
    plus = []
    f2 = open('path_to_file_b')

   for line in f2.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0]=='@':
            identifier.append(line)
            identifier.replace('@%s','>[i]' %(line))

        elif line[0]==('A' or 'G'or 'T' or 'U' or 'C'):
            seq = ','.join(line)
            sequence.append(seq)

        elif line[0]=='+'and line[1]=='' :
            plus.append(line)
            remove_line = file.writelines()

        elif line[0]!='@' or line[0]!=('A' or 'G'or 'T' or 'U' or 'C') or line[0]!='+' and line[1]!='':
            sanger.append(line)

        else:
            print("Danger Will Robinson, Danger!")


    f.write("'%s'\n '%s'\n '%s'" %(identifier, sequence, sanger))
    f.close()

    return (sanger,sequence,identifier,plus)
```

Now for my question. I have ran this and no error appears, however the target file is empty. I am wondering what I am doing wrong... Is it my way to handle the lists or the lack of .join? I am sorry if this is a duplicate. It is simply that I do not know what is the mistake here. Also, important note... This is not some homework, I just need a masker for work... Any help is greatly appreciated and all mentions of improvement to the code are welcomed. Thanks.

Note (fastq format):

```
@SRR566546.970 HWUSI-EAS1673_11067_FC7070M:4:1:2299:1109 length=50
TTGCCTGCCTATCATTTTAGTGCCTGTGAGGTGGAGATGTGAGGATCAGT

+

hhhhhhhhhhghhghhhhhfhhhhhfffffe`ee[`X]b[d[ed`[Y[^Y
```

Edit: Still unable to get anything, but working at it.

Comment: I think you should really take a look at [biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO).

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to test in your `if` and `else` statements, but the code you have is definitely not going to test it.

Comment: I think things like `if '@' == [0] in line:` were intended to be `if line[0] == '@':` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with your understanding of the return statement. `return x` means stop executing the current function and give `x` back to whoever called it. In your code you have:

```
return sanger
return sequence
return identifier
return plus
```

When the first one executes (`return sanger`) execution of the function stops and `sanger` is returned. The second through fourth return statements never get evaluated and neither does your I/O stuff at the end. If you're really interested in returning all of these values, move this after the file I/O and return the four of them packed up as a tuple.

```
f.write("'%s'\n '%s'\n '%s'" %(identifier, sequence, sanger))
f.close()
return (sanger,sequence,identifier,plus)
```

This should get you at least some output in the file. Whether or not that output is in the format you want, I can't really say.

Edit:
Just noticed you were using `/n` and probably want `\n` so I made the change in my answer here.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of the tuple... also, I still receive no output.

Answer (score 1):

You have all sorts of errors beyond what @Brian addressed. I'm guessing that your `if` and `else` tests are trying to check the first character of `line`? You'd do that with

```
if line[0] == '@':
    etc.
```

You'll probably need to write more scripts soon, so I suggest you work through the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) so you can get on top of the basics. It'll be worth your while.